# Is it possible to use line break in theme description?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I want to give linebreak on Wordpress theme's description in `style.css` (the one in here):

```
/*
Theme Name: 
Theme URI: 
Description: 
Author: 
Author URI: 
Version:
Tags: 
*/
```

But it appears the formatting doesn't allow any linebreak. When I tried writing on the line below it, the text won't appear. I tried adding `/n` as a mean to add linebreak, but the `/n/` wasn't read as linebreak.

Is it not possible to add linebreaks in Wordpress theme's description? I think linebreaks may be useful when theme designer wants to outline something in points/bullets (what I've been trying; that is I want to outline several features of the theme).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it not possible to add linebreaks in Wordpress theme's description?

No.

Sorry, to say - the question is valid, but I can't come up with a longer answer. Wouldn't make sense to explain the internals on this topic :)

Comment: Oh, ok! I wasn't expecting a long answer too :) Just want to know whether it's possible or not. Perhaps it could serve some use if it's made possible in future development. :?

Answer (score 3):

According to WP Source code you can add some HTML to your description: `<a>`, `<abbr>`, `<acronym>`, `<code>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`, but no elements with the `display: block` element.
`\n` and `<br>` do not work.
No way to add a line break, but possible to make it look nicer with HTML elements mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HTML entities, such as `&amp;nbsp;` (non-breaking space), so you can force a line-break by using these instead of normal spaces between the first few words of your new line, eg.

```html
This is the first line.  This&nbsp;is&nbsp;the&nbsp;second&nbsp;line bla-bla-bla`<br />
will render:<br /><br />
&emsp;This is the first line<br />
&emsp;This is the second line bla-bla-bla-bla ...
```

Messy, but it does the trick.  I also use &nbsp; when I don't want a name split by a line-break, eg. `Joe&nbsp;Bloggs`.
Just don't use too many `&amp;nbsp;`s together, else it will overflow the page.

Also note `&lt;span&gt;` statements don't work either.